# Expected value and variance of a sum of iid Bernoulli variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Suppose $x_1(j),x_2(j),...,x_n(j)$ are iid Bernoulli variables with probabilities $p_i(j)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-j-1}}$, for  $j=1,2,...100$ and a given value $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Let $y(j)=\sum_i x_i(j)$.
>
> Compute  $E(y)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(y)$.

I tried to compute the expected value of the array $(y)$ by using
$E(y)=∑_j jy(j)/(\sum_j)$ but the problem is that, I could not compute the sum of $x_i(j)$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please show what you have done already, Math.SE is not meant as a homework-doing machine.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I didn't mean to solve the homework and this is not a homework. I am newbie in the Bernoullie distribution. I tried to compute the expected value of the array (y) by using $E(y)=\sum_j j y(j)/(\sum j)$ but the problem is that, I could not compute the sum of $x_i(j)$.

Comment: Great. Could you possibly also tell us where you got this question? Where do you need it for?

Comment: This is an assignment in the maths course about Bernoulli distribution

Comment: What do you have for $P(x_i=j)$ ?

Comment: @calculus: I don't understand your question. \In fact it should be $x_i(j)$?

Comment: Other way round. What is the distribution of $x_i(j)$ ?

Comment: It is a Ber variable

Comment: Yes, but how does it look like ? Why you do not want to post it ?

Comment: The distribution of $x_i(j)$ is not undefined, I tried to compute it but not successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The long:**

$\begin{align}\mathsf E[Y(j)] & = \mathsf E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(j)\right] \\[1ex] & =\sum_{i=1}^n \mathsf E[X_i] & :\text{Linearity of Expectation} \\[1ex] & = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathsf P_i(j) & :\mathsf E[X_i] = 1\cdot P_i(j)+0\cdot(1-P_i(j)) \\[1ex] & =\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1+e^{-j-1}} \\[1ex] & = \frac{n}{1+e^{-j-1}}\end{align}$

---

Now can you find $\mathsf E[Y(j)^2]$ by a similar method, and thus obtain: $\mathsf {Var}(Y(j)) = \mathsf E[Y(j)^2] - \mathsf E^2[Y(j)]$ ?

> **Hint:** consider the value of $\mathsf E[X_iX_k]$ when (1) $ i=k$, (2) $i\neq k$.

---

**The short:**

> The sum of iid Bernouli distributed random variables is a Binomial distributed random variable.